# How does iPad OS determine what is a desktop site in iOS 13 safari

Tags: ios, ipad, webkit

In WWDC 2019 this year Apple stated that safari on the iPad will render a site in desktop. Is there any information or does anyone know how this will work?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this will be based on user agents.
iPads will start identifying themselves as Macs

From this….

> Mozilla/5.0(iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us)
>   AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B314
>   Safari/531.21.10

To this…

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15